# Ruby on Rails - hidden tag not passing into the database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Really new to RoR, and ran into an issue I can't find the answer to anywhere.

I have two tables, `user` and `books`, and I'm trying to use a join table to match up the user and the books and add a rating and review column in the join table. 
The problem is everything passes into the join table EXCEPT the `book_id`

**View**

```
<%= form_for(current_user.user_book_collections.build) do |f| %>
      <div>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :book_id, current_book.id %>
        <%= f.label :rating %>
        <%= f.text_field :rating, class:"form-control" %> 
        <%= f.label :review %> (optional):
        <%= f.text_area :review, size: "24x8", placeholder: "Please enter a brief review... ", class:"form-control" %>
      </div>
      <p></p>
      <%= f.submit "Add to your collection", class:"btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

`current_user` and `current_book` are methods where the users and books are assigned respectively.

**Controller**

```
def create
    @user_book_collection = current_user.user_book_collections.build(user_book_collection_params)
    if @user_book_collection.save
       flash[:success] = "Added to your collection"
       redirect_to mybooks_path
    else
       flash[:danger] = "Add was unsuccessful"
       redirect_to bookcollection_path
    end 
end 

private

   def user_book_collection_params
       params.require(:user_book_collection).permit( :book_id, :user_id, :review, :rating )
   end  
end
```

This is what shows up in the console:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"85gmzUO7ldQrevh/qnKwYO9mkd9lX77sG3xxJQV8Y46xZrkl5ifk665abPr79nOT91rO3oLcMSDgYL7BtR+/XQ==", "book_id"=>"6", "user_book_collection"=>{"rating"=>"s", "review"=>"asd"}, "commit"=>"Add to your collection"}
```

but then checking the record also in the console i can see the book_id did not pass through even though its been assigned in the parameters:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<UserBookCollection id: 10, user_id: 7, book_id: nil, review: "asd", rating: "s", created_at: "2016-02-07 06:36:33", updated_at: "2016-02-07 06:36:33">
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your form is constructed in a way the `book_id` is passed in `params[:book_id]`, not in `params[:user_book_collection][:book_id]` thus not present in `user_book_collection_params`

Use:

```
f.hidden_field :book_id, value: current_book.id
```

Comment: Using f.hidden_field results in the following error "undefined method `merge' for 4:Fixnum"

Comment: @jwon9615 forgot second param being hash in this case, use `value: ...` (edited)

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! what difference does adding the word "value:" make?

Comment: @jwon9615 it's a syntax for passing hash `{ :value => 'something'}`, needed because method signature is `hidden_field(object_name, method, options = {})`, ruby allows to write the last parameter that way

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.hidden_field :book_id, current_book.id %>
```

When using `form_for`, you need to bind the input method to the form object (as above).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rich Peck and Vasfeds excellent answers I would suggest you consider what you are doing from a REST point of view.

You want users to be able to add reviews to a book. Note that here UserBookCollections is just an ugly piece of plumbing - not really a resource which you would expose with REST. And calling it UserBookCollection is a bit misleading since each UserBookCollection is really just a link between one user and one book.

Also you want to avoid calling anything `Collection` in Rails since `ActiveRecord` uses the concept to denote a collection of linked records which may or may not be loaded - [you're going to confuse others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

This is one way to solve the same problem

```
class User
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :books, through: :reviews
end

class Review
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book 
end

class Book
  has_many :reviews, through: :reviews
end
```

Nice, now we have an object that we don't even have to explain what it does. So lets turn it into a RESTful resource:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :reviews, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  resources :books do
    resources :reviews, only: [:new, :create, :index], module: :books
  end

  resources :users do
    resources :reviews, only: [:index], module: :users
  end
end
```

This gives us routes with context:

```
         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                           Controller#Action
    edit_review GET    /reviews/:id/edit(.:format)           reviews#edit
         review GET    /reviews/:id(.:format)                reviews#show
                PATCH  /reviews/:id(.:format)                reviews#update
                PUT    /reviews/:id(.:format)                reviews#update
                DELETE /reviews/:id(.:format)                reviews#destroy
   book_reviews GET    /books/:book_id/reviews(.:format)     books/reviews#index
                POST   /books/:book_id/reviews(.:format)     books/reviews#create
new_book_review GET    /books/:book_id/reviews/new(.:format) books/reviews#new
   user_reviews GET    /users/:user_id/reviews(.:format)     users/reviews#index
```

Cool - now we have an API for Review with a built in context. The RESTful routes themselves tell us when we are creating a review for a certain book or looking at reviews by a certain user.

`module: :books` tells rails to link the nested routes to a "namespaced" controller instead of shoving everything into `ReviewsController`.

We setup our controllers as follows:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_review, only: [:edit, :show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /reviews/:id
  def show
  end 

  # GET /reviews
  def index
    @reviews = Review.all
  end

  # GET /reviews/:id/edit
  def edit
  end

  # PATCH /reviews/:id
  def update
    @review.update(review_params)
    respond_with(@review)
  end

  # DELETE /reviews/:id
  def destroy
    @review.destroy
    respond_with(@review)
  end

  private

    def set_review
      @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end

    def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :body) # note that you don't need book_id in here.
    end

end
```

---

```
# app/controllers/books/reviews_controller.rb
class Books::ReviewsController < ReviewsController

  before_action :set_book

  # GET /books/:book_id/reviews
  def index
    @reviews = Review.eager_load(:user, :book).where(book_id: params[:book_id])
  end 

  # GET /books/:book_id/reviews/new
  def new
    @review = @book.find(params[:book_id]).reviews.new
  end

  # POST /books/:book_id/reviews
  def create
    @review = @book.reviews.new(review_params) do |review|
      review.user = current_user
    end
    respond_with(@review)
  end

  private
    def set_book
      @book = Book).find(params[:book_id])
    end
end
```

---

```
# app/controllers/users/reviews_controller.rb
class Users::ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /users/:user_id/reviews
  def index
    @reviews = Review.joins(:user, :book).where(user_id: params[:user_id])
  end
end
```

You might question why you would want to use 3 controllers? It allows for a very clean mechanism of both code sharing and customizations. You can have different logic and views without creating a bunch of `if` or `switch` code paths.  Having many branches in a single action makes testing really messy and violates the skinny controllers paradigm.

The forms would look something like this:

```
# app/views/reviews/_fields.html.erb
<%= f.label :rating %>
<%= f.text_field :rating, class:"form-control" %> 
<%= f.label :body %> (optional):
<%= f.text_area :body, size: "24x8", placeholder: "Please enter a brief review... ", class:"form-control" %>
```

---

```
# app/views/books/reviews/new.erb
<%= form_for([@book, @review]) do |f| %>
  <%= render partial: 'reviews/fields', f: f %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
# app/views/books/edit.erb
<%= form_for(@review) do |f| %>
  <%= render partial: 'reviews/fields', f: f %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for that. Can definitely see the difference. So one question, if i want to add ratings, would it then make more sense to have another controller for "ratings" , or would you throw that into the review controller?